# Unicode strings in pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode, pydev

I'm using the pydev plugin for Eclipse and have run across the problem whilst trying to include unicode strings. As far as I can tell this is NOT the common problem of unicode compatibility between pydev and the python on the commandline.

If I use a unicode string such as the following:

```
INFINITY_STRING = u"\u5555"
```

pydev flags it with the error:

```
Multiple markers at this line

- occurrence
- Undefined variable: u
- Encountered "\"\\u5555\"" at line 54, column 13. Was expecting one of:     <NEWLINE>                    ...     "(" ...     "[" ...     ";" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...       "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...    
"<<" ...     ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     "=" ...     ">" ...     "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...     "!=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     "in" ...     "if" ...     
";" ...     "," ...
```

The code compiles and runs but this supposed error messes up the autocompletion and refactoring features. Does anyone know how to prevent pydev from throwing an error when presented with unicode strings?

Comment: I can't see any problem with that on a Win7, Eclipse 3.6.1, Python 2.6 and pydev 2.7.1. Maybe it helps, if you specify the coding (e.g. # -*- coding: utf-8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have configured pydev to run the code with Python 3 but you use Python 2 on the command line.

[Python 3.0 doesn't support the `u` prefix for strings](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) anymore; all strings in Python 3 are already Unicode.

Note that it has been restored with Python 3.3 ([PEP-0414](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/), [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.3.0/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)). Kudos to [Janne Karila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222914/janne-karila) for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, you were completely right, I'd got confused whether you needed the "u" in python 3.3 or not.